# Complex numbers in VBA

Tags: option-pricing, excel, vba, characteristic-function

Hey I try to price options in VBA. To do this I need to define characteristic function and do some operations on complex numbers.  For example I have this code:

```
Function cf(u, T, r, q, sigma)
i = WorksheetFunction.Complex(0, 1)
b = r - q - 0.5 * sigma ^ 2
cf = WorksheetFunction.ImExp(T * (i * u * b - 0.5 * u ^ 2 * sigma ^ 2)
End Function
```

But it doesnt work. I know that WorksheetFunction.Complex(0, 1) returns string and I wonder how to do this to make this code work. Maybe there are some better libraries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ahhh complex numbers in Excel VBA, the pinnacle of cubicle programming. *Been there, done that!*

The functions that you quote are indeed [returning `string` types.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.complex) But you should be able to compose those functions, e.g.

```
Option Explicit
Public Function cf(u As Double, ttm As Double, rf As Double, q As Double, s As Double) As String
    Dim b As Double
    b = rf - q - 0.5 * s ^ 2
    If u = 0 Then
        cf = "1.0"
    Else
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            cf = .ImExp(.Complex(-0.5 * u ^ 2 * s ^ 2 * ttm, ttm * u * b))
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

This function will now return a **string** type, but Excel can nevertheless consume it:

```
Sub ATest()
    Dim z1 As String, z2 As String, z3 As String
    Dim x1 As Double, x2 As Double
   ' some parameters
    Const ttm As Double = 1#
    Const rf As Double = 0.05
    Const q As Double = 0#
    Const sigma As Double = 0.2
    Const eps As Double = 0.0001
    
    z1 = cf(-eps, ttm, rf, q, sigma)
    z2 = cf(0, ttm, rf, q, sigma)
    z3 = cf(eps, ttm, rf, q, sigma)
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        x1 = .ImReal(.ImDiv( _
                    .ImSub(z3, z1), _
                    .Complex(0, 2 * eps))) ' first moment estimator
        x2 = .ImReal(.ImDiv( _
                        .ImSum(.ImSub(z1, z2), .ImSub(z3, z2)), _
                        .Complex(-eps * eps, 0))) ' second moment estimator
    End With
    Debug.Print "drift:", Round(CDbl(x1), 6), (rf - 0.5 * sigma ^ 2) * ttm
    Debug.Print "variance:", Round(CDbl(x2) - CDbl(x1) ^ 2, 6), sigma ^ 2 * ttm
End Sub
```

will result in

```
drift:         0,03          0,03 
variance:      0,04          0,04
```

i.e. the return expectation.

If you want another implementation, there is one available at [pfadintegral](https://pfadintegral.com/articles/complex-numbers-vba/) (I have never checked it). Another path, of course, would be to compose your own library in VBA (as I said, *been there, done that!*), but I think it may not be worthwile as there are many cornercases to think about, e.g. branch cutting, numerical underflow etc. ...

HTH?

Comment: I remember implementing a code that prints out a mandelbrot set on the screen: the way I did that was to simply define a complex number as $c=a+b$, where both $a$ and $b$ are regular floats and $b$ represents the imaginary part. Then, one can work out operations such as $c^2$ using the logic: "$Real = a^2-b^2$", "$Complex = 2ab$". I think it's possible to work with complex numbers without having to call excel "complex" functions: instead, one can just code up logic that works out the real and imaginary parts of various operations....

Comment: Hi @JanStuller yes that works to some extent. But at some point you want to introduce complex log, exp, etc... that’s where the fun begins. I ended up with a class for all these operations, and „my“ complex integral in VBA is still a bit off due to numerical underflows in some angle calculations  :-D

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you / have you ever used Complex numbers for anything in finance?

Comment: Yes! The whole FFT Based option pricing stuff based on Duffie/Pan/Singleton 2000!

Comment: Oh wow! Ok, I gotta look into that! Haven't come across it so far, sounds interesting!